# How do I change the AudioPlayer directive, "play the audio," in the Alexa sample nodejs audio player project?

Tags: node.js, audio, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to building Skills for Alexa, and am currently building one off of the sample audio player skill provided here:

https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

I am trying to change what Alexa listens for in order to begin the podcast ("play the audio"), but I can't locate it in the code.

```
var message = 'Welcome to the AWS Podcast. You can say, play the audio to begin the podcast.';
var reprompt = 'You can say, play the audio, to begin.';
```

Can someone point me to where I configure this?

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this link https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/blob/mainline/js/stateHandlers.js do you see `this.response.speak(theMessage)` that's the function that does.

You should be able to change the parameter `theMessage` as you like.